# Deleting templated C++ 2-dimensional array

Tags: c++, templates, destructor

Annoyance over C++'s requirement to pass a dimension in a 2-d array got me working on a templated Matrix class. I've been coding in C# for a bit, so I'm sure I'm a little rusty here.

Issue is, I get a heap exception as soon as I hit the destructor, which is trying to delete the 2-d array.

Any help gratefully accepted!

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(int m, int n) : nRows(m), nCols(n) { 
        pMatrix = new T * [nRows]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < nCols; i++) {
            pMatrix[i] = new T[nCols];
        }
    }
    ~Matrix() { 
        if (pMatrix != NULL) { 
            for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) { delete[] pMatrix[i]; }
            delete[] pMatrix;
        }
    }
    T ** GetMatrix() const { return pMatrix; }
    T * Row(int i) const { return pMatrix[i]; }
    inline T Cell(int row, int col) const { return pMatrix[row][col]; }
    inline int GetNRows() const { return nRows; }
    inline int GetNCols() const { return nCols; }
private:
    int nRows, nCols;
    T ** pMatrix;
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to return a `T**` and a `T*`? To me that seems like exposing inner implementation details. And you could simplify the code by using a single `std::vector` and playing with the indices for access.

Comment: Completely concur with Juan. You can make this *significantly* simpler by using an `std::vector<>` and a simple `i*cols+j` to get the `[i][j]` element. The only thing you would be missing is the ability to perform double-bracket dereferencing, and even that you can conquer with a creative subclass that returns a row-iterator.

Comment: Agreed, and see answer for an even more elegant solution similar to these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the bug, @CodeChords_man explained it right. I have notes on implementation. I recommend to look through [this wonderful FAQ post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible).

You should not use dynamic memory allocation unless you are 100% sure that

1. You *really* need it
2. You know how to implement it

I don't know of the first, and how the performance is crucial for you. But as for the second, you at least violated the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). You class is very unsafe to use. If you copy it, the memory buffer will then be double-deleted.

You should not afraid to used STL containers, they are fast and optimized. At least the `std::vector`, it is as fast as the raw pointer in many scenarios. You can rewrite you class using `std::vector` as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
  typedef std::vector<T> MatrixRow;
  typedef std::vector<MatrixRow> MatrixBody;

  Matrix(int m, int n) : nRows(m), nCols(n), _body(m, MatrixRow(n)) {}

  const MatrixBody& GetMatrix() const { return _body; }
  const MatrixRow& GetRow(int i) const { return _body[i]; }

  inline T Cell(int row, int col) const { return _body[row][col]; }
  inline int GetNRows() const { return nRows; }
  inline int GetNCols() const { return nCols; }
private:
  int nRows, nCols;
  MatrixBody _body;
};
```

Since this class is not using dynamic memory allocation, it is safe to copy and assign. You also don't need to explicitly store `nRows` and `nCols` in this case; you can use `_body.size()` and `_body[0].size()` instead.

Concerning underlying vector of vectors, it is dereferenced using the same `[i][j]` construction. It is easily iterated with `begin()` and `end()`. And if you absolutely need to use the raw pointer in some routine, you can always access it with `&row[0]`.

The only possible difficulty is that you cannot easily convert `MatrixBody` to `T**`. But think it twice, maybe you don't really need to use `T**` at all.

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more, on all counts! I've fixed the bug; I'll go after using STL now. I originally come from a deeply embedded environment where STL can't be used (size). This is a good tip, and I'll try it and let you know how it works.

Comment: Glad for you! Consider upvoting or even accepting my answer then :)

Comment: I'm getting greedy now - I'm going to go figure out how to overload the []s so I don't have to use the awkward "GetMatrix" syntax :)

Comment: You can use `MatrixBody` as a matrix itself. In this case you can go without implementing any additional class. You won't be able to construct it with `(m, n)` in this case, however. Anyway, implementing `operator[]()` is easy, straightforward and appropriate in this case, so go for it. Remember, you only need to replace `GetRow` with it. After you get `vector`, the second `[]` will work automatically.

Comment: I was just coming around to the question of why bother with the Matrix class. Nice construction is what I got to, too. Thanks for the tip on the operator[] - my search had just turned up the need for a proxy to operate the second [] on, but you're right, the vector fills that need! I'd upvote you three times if I could.

Comment: Thanks again - final class follows.
    #include <vector>

    template <typename T>
    class Matrix {
    public:
        typedef std::vector<T> MatrixRow;
        typedef std::vector<MatrixRow> MatrixBody;

        Matrix(int m, int n) : nRows(m), nCols(n), _body(m, MatrixRow(n)) {}
        inline int GetNRows() const { return nRows; }
        inline int GetNCols() const { return nCols; }
        inline MatrixRow & operator[](int index) { return _body[index]; }
        inline MatrixBody & Get() { return _body; }
    private:
        int nRows, nCols;
        MatrixBody _body;
    };

Comment: I have tried everything I can think of to format the above, but without success.  At least the class is there, if you'd like to see it.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly use `inline` - methods, defined within the class declaration, are implicitly marked inline. I recommend to add const-flavors of `Get()` and `operator[]()`. I also suggest to rename `Get()` to more meaningful `GetBody()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the bug:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nCols; i++) {
        pMatrix[i] = new T[nCols];
}
```

The loop should be until `nRows`, not `nCols`.

Other than that, let me tell you about something I did when I got tired of allocating 2-d arrays. I had to do a 3-d array. I used a `map`, that mapped from a coordinate - a struct holding x, y, z to the type I wanted.

I worked fast, and no need to allocate or deallocate. Assigning to a coordinate was simply done by

```
mymap[Coord(x, y, z)] = whatever...
```

Of course I needed to define the `Coord` struct and overload the `< operator`, but I found that way more comvenient than trying to allocate and deallocate a 3-d array.

Of course you will need to check if this scheme is fast enough for you. I used it to draw cells within a big cube using OpenGL and had no complaints at all.